# image comparison in R

Tags: r, image-processing, matrix

I am looking for the best way to compare 2 or more images.
The images I have are now in matrix format, so basically I am comparing matrices.

They aren't square (but this isn't a problem).
This is an example of what I have with only two matrices:

```
#Original data
M1<-cbind(c(0,0,20,40,50,35),c(0,0,5,20,90,80),c(0,0,10,25,85,0),c(58,70,20,50,0,5))
#Data to be compared with M1
M2<-cbind(c(0,5,25,25,60,15),c(0,30,15,10,116,67),c(0,2,9,20,90,1),c(69,50,22,30,0,2))
```

I can check for the differences and the correlation, but I also want to be able to say for example, if:

- high values in M2 occur in the same positions that M1
- high values in M2 occur close to the positions in M1
- high values in M2 occur far away

Same thing for low values.

By high values I mean maximum values, for example if the max value in M1 is in position (M1_maxvalue(x,y)), than I M2 max value should be a similar value observed in M1 as well as in the same or close position M1_maxvalue(x,y).

I can extract the positions, the variation of the positions of the maximum values, however I am looking for existent methods where I can base my comparisons.

What type of calculations can I use to do such type of analysis?
I can use both image processing packages as well as matrices algorithms.

Comment: Define 'high values' - do you mean just the minimums and maximums or a more broad high/low?

Comment: Have you tried a `mantel test`? That might be better than just straight correlation. See `mantel.rtest` in the `ade4` package.

Comment: I did check a while ago the package @Manetheran, but I will double-check if I can do what I want.

Comment: You can do simple things like: `which(M1==max(M1),arr.ind=TRUE)` to get the row/col location of the maximum values.

Comment: @thelatemail yes I already do that, but what I am looking for is for existent methods/algorithms that allow me to go in detail for the comparison of matrices and images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job better handled with `ImageJ` or `SAODS9`  at http://hea-www.harvard.edu/RD/ds9/ .

IIRC those apps have built-in tools for spot and blob-finding, which may save you a lot of time and pain.